# How can I add two values to a class attribute?

Tags: php, class, echo

I'm trying to add two classes to a `td` by echoing them out. All of them contain one class every time, but the other class can change. I hop into the function which just has all of the classes in an array as follows...

```
$StandClassArray = array('north stand', 'east stand', 'south stand', 'west stand');
```

Note that these SHOULD be two separate classes, one is called 'stand' and one is called 'north' or 'south' etc. So all `td`'s need the 'stand' class and one of the 4 compass points.

When I add this to my `td` with the following....

```
$Side = 0 ; // This would have been passed to the function usually.
echo "<td class = $StandClassArray[$Side]>Text</td>";
```

What I get in the browser is ...

```
<td class = "north" stand = "">Text</td>
```

I've tried doing it other ways, such as ...

```
echo "<td class = $StandClassArray[$Side] stand>Text</td>"; // Just the compass point in the array for this.
```

But it gives the same result.

I'm pretty sure that I've had this problem before, ages ago, but can't remember how to fix it.

Comment: You need to wrap the value of your html attribute in quotes, especially if the value contains a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just echo the value:

```
<td class="<?php echo $StandClassArray[$Side] ?>">Text</td>
```

Another approach may be (following your logic):

```
echo "<td class ='".$StandClassArray[$Side]."'>Text</td>";
```

Comment: Ah I see, there were no quotes in my final output. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The actual output to the browser was:

```
<td class = north stand>Text</td>
```

Which isn't valid markup.  The browser was trying to correct it for you as best it could.  Just be explicit about the output, to include the quotes where you want them included:

```
echo "<td class = \"$StandClassArray[$Side]\">Text</td>";
```

Which should output:

```
<td class = "north stand">Text</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I had no quotes in the final string at all. Doh.